# Matching logical subscripts to the size of the indexed input

Tags: r, list, attributes

I have created two data frames that I then turn into lists (e.g., `list1` and `list2`). I removed one element from `list2` to better represent my example data set.

```
library(dplyr)

intervals <- rep_len(c("01-01-2022", "01-11-2022", "01-31-2022"), 100)
ID <- rep(c("A","B", "C"), 100)
df <- data.frame(ID = as.factor(ID),
                 intervals = as.factor(intervals))

list1 <- df %>% 
  group_by(ID, intervals) %>% 
  group_split()

intervals <- rep_len(c("01-01-2022", "01-11-2022", "01-31-2022"), 25)
ID <- rep(c("A","B"), 25)
df2 <- data.frame(ID = as.factor(ID),
                 intervals = as.factor(intervals))

list2 <- df2 %>% 
  group_by(ID, intervals) %>% 
  group_split()

list2 <- list2[-6]
```

For each of these list I have added an attribute, and I have included a function to check the added attribute more readily (`check`).

```
# Convenience function to grab the attributes for you
check <- function(list, attribute_name) {
  return(attr(list, attribute_name))
}

# Add an attribute to hold the attributes of each list element
attr(list1, "match") <- data.frame(id = sapply(list1, function(x) paste(x$ID[1])),
                                  interval_start_date = sapply(list1, function(x) paste(x$intervals[1]))
)

# Check the attributes
check(list1, "match")

# Add an attribute "tab" to hold the attributes of each list element
attr(list2, "match") <- data.frame(id = sapply(list2, function(x) paste(x$ID[1])),
                                  interval_start_date = sapply(list2, function(x) paste(x$intervals[1]))
) 

# Check the attributes
check(list2, "match")
```

I have created an index for the two list, and the objective here is to remove any list components that don't have the same `ID` and the same `intervals`. The goal is to have only the matching `ID`s with the same `intervals`.

```
# Creates an index for the two list based on the attributes, 
dat2 <- check(list1, "match")
dat1 <- check(list2, "match")

# Removes rows where the id isn't present in both data frames, and creates a 
# index where both the interval and id are the same.
if (!length(unique(dat2$id)) == length(unique(dat1$id))){
  dat3 <- dat2[dat2$id %in% dat1$id, ]
  dat4 <- dat1[dat1$id %in% dat2$id, ]
  
  i1 <-   paste(dat3[["id"]], format(as.Date(dat3[["interval_"]]),
                                     "%Y-%d")) %in%  
    paste(dat4[["id"]], format(as.Date(dat4[["interval_"]]), 
                               "%Y-%d"))
}
```

Now here is where I begin to get an error:

```
# Error occurs because the lengths of `i1` is not the same as `list2`
out <- list1[i1]
```

I know that this is occuring because `list1` does not have the same length as `i1`. I'm wondering if there is a way to appending logical values to `i1` to get it the same length as `list1`, but in a way that it doesn't remove values from `list1` that we actually do want to keep. Any thoughts?

Here is my expected output for `list1`, where I hope it ends up with only the same `ID`s and `intervals` as `list2`.

```
# Expected output
expected_list1 <- list(list1[1], list1[2],list1[3], list1[4], list1[5])
```

This answer is close to what I would like, but it has an additional element. I think ultimately the attribute table should be similiar to that of `dat4`.

```
 test <- list1[dat2$id %in% dat1$id][i1]
 # Add an attribute "tab" to hold the attributes of each list element
 attr(test, "match") <- data.frame(id = sapply(test, function(x) paste(x$ID[1])),
                                    interval_start_date = sapply(test, function(x) paste(x$intervals[1]))
 ) 
 
 # Check the attributes
 check(test, "match")
```

Comment: There is a reason for that i.e. your `i1` is based on `dat3` and `dat4` which is a subset of `list1`. So, I guess you need the `list1`, length to be the same as length of i1

Comment: Do you need `list1[dat2$id %in% dat1$id][i1]`

Comment: I think it is close to what I want, but it has an extra element that should have been removed.

Comment: would this be more helpful to first subset by the dat1, dat2, to create the 'i1' and then remove the ones that doesn't have common ids

Comment: The function when I tested, it returns 6 TRUE cases for `i1` Is there something missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a mismatch in the column name i.e. it is not `interval_`, but `interval_start_date` in `dat1` and `dat2`.  `[[` will look for exact match whereas `$` can match partial names as well

```
if (!length(unique(dat2$id)) == length(unique(dat1$id))){
 ids_common <- intersect(dat2$id, dat1$id)
 inds1 <- dat2$id %in% ids_common
 inds2 <- dat1$id %in% ids_common
 i1 <-   paste(dat2[["id"]], format(as.Date(dat2[["interval_start_date"]]),
                                    "%Y-%d")) %in%  
   paste(dat1[["id"]], format(as.Date(dat1[["interval_start_date"]]), 
                              "%Y-%d"))
 
  out <- list1[i1 & inds1]
  
 
}
```

-checking

```
> length(out)
[1] 5
> i1
[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```